# I'm stuck with displaying this api on vue

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, strapi

i'm starting to learn how to use API but i'm stuck, so this is the API, http://localhost:1337/handies

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "price": "7€/h",
    "description": "Nice guy che vuole lavorare molto e non ha paura di sporcarsi le mani",
    "created_at": "2021-05-05T07:57:29.038Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-05T09:16:21.476Z",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Idraulico",
            "created_at": "2021-05-05T08:34:52.646Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-05-05T08:34:58.981Z"
        }
    ]
},
```

now if I with vue want to visualize the name i write `{{handies.name}}` and it work perfectly, but if i want print the categories name "idraulico" i try `{{handies.categories.name}}` but don't work...what's the way to display the categories name? i use vue, axios and strapi.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `{{handies.categories[0].name}}` to print the name of first category.

To print them all you can use [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) directive, something like

```html
<div v-for="category in handies.categories" :key="category.id">
   {{ category.name }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following format.

```
   <div v-for="handy in handies" :key="handy.id">
      <div>{{ handy.name }}</div>
      <div>Categiries</div>
      <div v-for="category in handy.categories" :key="category.id">
        <div>{{ category.name }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Using index as key is a bad practice and should be avoided when possible. Also OP has direct access to the object since `{{handies.name}}` is working for him

Answer (score 0):

categories is an Array, you have to speicifed the index.
I recommend to you to study a little of basic programming